# Determine whether or not $card(A^B)>card(C^D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let's say I have $4$ sets: $A,B,C,D$, is there a way to determine whether or not $\left|A^B\right|>\left|C^D\right|$?

I thought about this question because it is easy to show that $\left|n^\Bbb N\right|=\left|m^\Bbb N\right|$ forall $n,m\in\Bbb N$, but also $\left|\Bbb N^\Bbb N\right|$ is equal to the above. I was also told that  $\left|\Bbb R^\Bbb N\right|$ is equal to them(although I didn't prove that one), so $\left|n^\Bbb N\right|=\left|\Bbb N^\Bbb N\right|=\left|\Bbb R^1\right|=\left|\Bbb R^\Bbb N\right|$, it means that simply compare $|B|$ with $|D|$ and $|A|$ with $|C|$ won't be enough.

Also, what about the other direction? If $\left|A^B\right|>\left|C^D\right|$ what can we say about the relation of the cardinality of $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: $\vert\Bbb R^{\Bbb N} \vert=\vert (2^{\Bbb N})^{\Bbb N} \vert$

Comment: @Berci if you mean to use that to prove $\vert\Bbb R^{\Bbb N} \vert=\vert \Bbb R \vert$, then thanks, if it meant to be a hint for the question itself I don't understand it.

Comment: In general cardinal exponentiation is a wild card, so there is *really* no easy answer to give you here. I feel that you're asking from a naive point of view (given your statement about $\Bbb{R^N}$), in which case you might be interested only in a few sets, or type of sets.

Comment: Adding to the comment by Asaf Karagila, it has been shown by advanced methods that it is consistent with ZFC (the "standard" axiom system of set theory) that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_1^{\aleph_1}$ are equal but also consistent with ZFC that  they are not equal.  It is a "wild card".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet so, atleast to $\aleph_{0,1}$, we have to try to prove it case by case?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I still only started study axiomatic set theory, this question is not part of the course, I just thought about it and was interested so I didn't thought about specific type of sets. Can you give me an example of type of sets this problem has an answer?

Comment: It would be instructive to try and find a *simple* solution for *finite* sets first. If you can do that, we can talk about the infinite case. I guess the complexity should be about the same separation into four cases, with the added caveat that we can hardly prove anything about exponentiation of infinite sets. (It's not just $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$, it's "practically all of them".)

Comment: When A,B,C,D are infinite there are a very limited number of generalities available,e.g. Konig's Theorem & consequences of it (such as $cf(2^a)>a$), and $2^B>B$ (Cantor's  classic result)) because the axiom system ZFC cannot prove or disprove many cardinal inequalities, which is demonstrable using Forcing, a method developed by Paul Cohen in the 1960's.Forcing is considered an advanced topic because you need a thorough background in the basics of Set Theory (and preferably some Model Theory) to understand any of it